# WPF DataGridTextColumn UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged does not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I know this is a known problem. What I want is that the data source is updated as the user types. You can do this with a DataGridTemplateColumn which wraps around a TextBox, but this results in a performance hit, DataGridTextColumn is a lot more efficient.

I have already extended DataGridTextColumn but there are no events I can use to get the functionality I desire.

Is there anything I can do?

Kind regards,
Fugu

edit: As requested here is a XAML snippet:

Here is the DataGrid:

```
<UserControls:CommandDataGrid Name="dgCLASS_MN" 
Command="{x:Static my2:Commands.ClassVRPopulateCommand}"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ClassViewModel}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainTableView}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MainTableSelectedRow}"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
ClipToBounds="True"
SelectedCellsChanged="SelectedCellsChanged">
```

And here is one of the columns.

```
<UserControls:FreezableDataGridTextColumn Header="BASE_LANGUAGE_NAME" 
    SortMemberPath="BASE_LANGUAGE_NAME" Binding="{Binding Path=BASE_LANGUAGE_NAME, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

FreezableDataGridTextColumn descends from DataGridTextColumn which poses the same problem.

The DataGrid is bound to a DataTableView in the code behind.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not working and you are not making any mistake in binding? can you post your XAML and Code?

Comment: I would change the `DataGridTextColumn` to the `DataGridTemplateColumn`. It often works.

Comment: Hi vorrtex, that would work but as I said the DataGridTextColumn is a lot more efficient, DataGridTemplateColumn with text boxes inside is too slow for our purposes.